# How to fix Uncaught Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js from reCaptcha

Tags: recaptcha

My site is slow after adding recaptcha, so looking at Google Developers Console I see some errors. I have been using v2 of recaptcha then tried to switch to v3 but had no luck, so I switch back and I think some of the errors are remnants or left over code from v3. I am not sure how to find and remove. I thought I had it all removed but must not.

I thought I had removed all forms of code related to v3 but with this error and that key I must not have.

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js: 
XXxXxXXXXXXXXXxxxXxXxxXXXxXxXXXxXXxXxXWXx
at Object.Gu [as execute] (VM3003 recaptcha__en.js:513)
at Object.execute ((index):273)
at executeOnHomepage ((index):273)
at A4 (VM3003 recaptcha__en.js:512)
at X (VM3003 recaptcha__en.js:518)
```

I would like to remove get rid of this error so my site loads faster and continue to improve my site performance.